# How to execute key pair generation in jmeter

Tags: java, jmeter

We need to load test our portal for registering android devices on it using JMeter. I want to register fake devices as the load is for 500+ devices.  The device is supposed to generate a keypair using RSA algo. and hash of the public key.  I want to execute a java code for the same and use the generated pair in my HTTP Sampler. is there any other way to do it??

Comment: generate all keys on devices and write them in a file and use that file as csv data config file and then use it in Jmeter to register device on portal.

Comment: We have the java code for key generation,how can we use it in jmeter?

Comment: If you have code then put it in beanshell preprocessor and save the key in a variable and use it in successor request to register device.